# interpolate data frame based on dates in r

Tags: r, date, dataframe, interpolation

I'd like to optimize my procedure to interpolate a data frame column based on sequence of date.
Here's the deal. I have a data frame with two columns such as

```
d <- data.frame(x=c("2012-01-01","2013-01-01","2014-01-01","2015-01-01","2016-01-01","2017-01-01","2018-01-01","2019-01-01"),
                y=c(70, 80, 90, 80, 75 ,70, 75, 60))
```

I'd like to expand this data frame over a sequence of dates by months so

```
xx <- seq(as.Date(x[1]),as.Date(x[length(x)]),by="months")
```

and then interpolate my second column above over this sequence.
This is what I did,

```
# initialize the final data frame
r <- data.frame(matrix(NA,length(xx),2))
# copy the data I know
for (i in 1:length(x))
  r[which(xx==as.Date(d$x[i])),] <- d[i,]
# set the date sequence on the first column
r[,1] <- as.character(xx,"%Y/%m/%d")
# interpolate the values on the second column
r[,2] <- as.numeric(na.approx(r[,2]))
```

is there a better and more elegant way to do this? maybe in just one shot.

Comment: Check out the [approxfun](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/approxfun.html).

Comment: thanks! I tried but I guess I didn't get how to use it. I typed:
`f <- approxfun(d$x, d$y)` and then `f(xx)` but I got an array of NA